# When a sorcerers bloodline states they can change a spell's element, what happens to extra effects?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

When a sorcerer of a fire bloodline changes a spell's elemental damage from, say cold, to fire, but the spell has additional effects, say, creating an [ice slick](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/ice-slick) on the ground to make enemies slip, what happens to that effect? Does the spell spit out fire, and leave behind ice? Or does its extra effect flavor for the new element, creating bizarre situations?

Comment: Sorry About the duplicate. Couldnt find that specific question as I was thinking too generally. Hopefully the title of this will be easier to find and lead people to the Correct answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It does nothing except change the damage type and the descriptors on the spell. The extra effects that are not damage still occur as stated and are not changed, because they are not damage types.